# What happens when i using @Bean and @Component annotations together?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to configure my spring security application.

I want to create my own UserDetailsService.

For that i do something like this:

```
public class ApplicationUserService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return this.someUser();
    }
}
```

I got 2 ways to add this UserService to Spring Security

1. Add it to configuration class. Something like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    @Override
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return applicationUserService;
    }
}
```

2. Or add annotaion @Component, or @Service on my class.
   Everything is working fine when i chose only 1 way, but i got an question: why when i trying to use both variants (add @Service and add @Bean to config) nothing is working?
   I got no exceptions, error or something like this in console:

```
2021-09-11 17:26:16.755  INFO 15819 --- [           main] com.example.test.TestApplication         : Starting TestApplication using Java 16.0.2 on aleksander-MS-7A71 with PID 15819 (/home/aleksander/programming/java/4fun/test/target/classes started by aleksander in /home/aleksander/programming/java/4fun/test)
2021-09-11 17:26:16.756  INFO 15819 --- [           main] com.example.test.TestApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-09-11 17:26:17.402  INFO 15819 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-09-11 17:26:17.409  INFO 15819 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-09-11 17:26:17.409  INFO 15819 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.52]
2021-09-11 17:26:17.442  INFO 15819 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-09-11 17:26:17.442  INFO 15819 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 630 ms
2021-09-11 17:26:17.555  INFO 15819 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@6981f8f3, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@38bb9d7a, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@62db3891, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@48528634, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@80bfdc6, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@78d6447a, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@5e65afb6, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@623dcf2a, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@2819c460, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@6f49d153, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@60bbacfc]
2021-09-11 17:26:17.676  INFO 15819 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-09-11 17:26:17.682  INFO 15819 --- [           main] com.example.test.TestApplication         : Started TestApplication in 1.215 seconds (JVM running for 1.794)
```

Comment: you dont need the override https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-userdetailsservice

Answer (score 0):

The way you've described the question, the application will definitely throw an exception unless you've defined the bean preference.

**First case:**
Basically, `UserDetailsService` is an `interface` and you've provided the implementation of it by declaring the bean as

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    @Override
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new ApplicationUserService();
    }
}
```

**Second case:** You want to check the behaviour by declaring another bean using `@Service` or `@Component` annotation as following

```
@Service
public class ApplicationUserService implements UserDetailsService {  
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return new UserDetails();
    }
}
```

If you try to use the above cases together, it won't work. The case is very simple you are providing two beans of type `UserDetailsService` to the spring container and hence it won't be able to identify which one it should use.

If you want to check the behaviour with both the cases you've to set the priority for beans, so in that case you can mark one of the bean with `@Primary` annotation.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Primary
    @Bean
    @Override
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new ApplicationUserService();
    }
}
```